# how to hide tags using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>welcome to Wall Street model</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#c").click(function(){
    $("h1").hide();
});
</script>

</head>  

<button id="c">click to hide</button>

<h1>this is a message</h1>
</body>
</html>**
```

I am new to jQuery.  i tried this code to hide the h1 tags when button is clicked.but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing code you need to make sure *all* the syntax is correct:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#c").click(function(){
        $("h1").hide();
});
```

Here you forgot a `});`. It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#c").click(function(){
        $("h1").hide();
    });
});
```

You JavaScript won't work because when the browser runs into *one* problem it will immediately stop executing JavaScript.

### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cunacowiju/1/)

Comment: @smasher If this helped you, you can click the checkmark next to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Missing `});` Can find demo in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/9212hn2e/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#c").click(function(){
    $("h1").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```